# Get field of JSON in Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like this, how to get the value of `StatusDescription`? I tried many times but the result is undefined. Here is my JSON:

```
 {
  "meta": {
    "a2": 200,
    "ta": "dasd",
    "asdd": "asdda"
  },
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "number": "",
        "origin_info": {
          "ItemReceived": "2021-10-02 02:07:49",
          "phone": 123456789,
          "trackinfo": [
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            },
   
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            }
          ]
        },
        "destination_info": null,
        "lastEvent": "grgrgrgrgr",
        "lastUpdateTime": "mewmemew"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using in my NodeJS app, like `myapp.js`, and `console.log()`

Comment: You have provided just Json only. How do you want to access it ? Where are you accessing it ? Which platform are you using ? Please provide details.

Comment: edited ^^!, tks bro!

Comment: please also try what you have added, otherwise, it might get downvoted very quickly

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through your `items` and `trackinfo` to get to `StatusDescription`. Try this one.

```js
const data =  {
  "meta": {
    "a2": 200,
    "ta": "dasd",
    "asdd": "asdda"
  },
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "number": "",
        "origin_info": {
          "ItemReceived": "2021-10-02 02:07:49",
          "phone": 123456789,
          "trackinfo": [
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            },
   
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            }
          ]
        },
        "destination_info": null,
        "lastEvent": "grgrgrgrgr",
        "lastUpdateTime": "mewmemew"
      }
    ]
  }
}

const items = data.data.items.map(item => item)
const trackinfo = items.map(item => item.origin_info.trackinfo).flat()
console.log(trackinfo)
const statusDescription = trackinfo.map(trackinfo => trackinfo.StatusDescription)

console.log(statusDescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I stored your sample json in variable `json`

```
var json = {
  "meta": {
    "a2": 200,
    "ta": "dasd",
    "asdd": "asdda"
  },
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "number": "",
        "origin_info": {
          "ItemReceived": "2021-10-02 02:07:49",
          "phone": 123456789,
          "trackinfo": [
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            },
   
            {
              "StatusDescription": "what i need",
              "Details": "",
              "substatus": "ok"
            }
          ]
        },
        "destination_info": null,
        "lastEvent": "grgrgrgrgr",
        "lastUpdateTime": "mewmemew"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Accessed it like below

```
console.log(json.data.items[0].origin_info.trackinfo[0].StatusDescription);
```

`Items` is an array and we took array element `0`.

`trackinfo` again is an array and we took array element `0`.

We can change array index or loop through and get required values.